# GMAT exam question about finding a quadratic equation given mistakes in solving it

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

In solving a problem on quadratic equation, one student makes a mistake in the constant term of the equation and gets $-3$ and $-2$ for the roots. Another student makes a mistake in the coefficient of first degree term and finds $-1$ and $-2$ for the roots. What is the correct equation?

What I did:-
Let a and b be the roots of the equation
For the first mistake
$a+b=5$( Sum of roots)
$ab=6$

For the second mistake
$a+b=-3$
$ab=3$
Answer of this question is 
$x^2+5x+2$
How can we get the answer of this question when we have been wrong values?
I will be obliged if anyone of you can help me with this question

Comment: This must be a typo, because $x^2+5^x+2$ is not a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 3):

The original equation is $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

The first equation is $ax^2+bx+c'=0$. Then $-\dfrac ba =(-3)+(-2)=-5$ and so $\dfrac ba =5$.

The second equation is $ax^2+b'x+c=0$. Then $\dfrac ca=(-1)\cdot(-2)=2$.

So, the original equation is $ax^2+5ax+2a=0$ or, equivalently, $x^2+5x+2=0$, since $a\ne 0$.

Note that we *cannot* say what the original equation really was, because we don't know $a$, but we can find the roots.

Comment: How can we say that -3 and -2 can be the root of the equation if we can not tell about the original equation? @lhf

Comment: @anglena example - all quadratics of the form $kx(x-1)$ have the roots $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the coefficient of $x^2$ is $1$, the equation will be $x^2+5x+2=0$. In fact:

- from the first mistake, we get that the sum of the coefficient of $x$ is $5$;
- from the second mistake, we get that the constant term is $2$.